# Редирект страниц постраничной навигации раздела с GET-переменной

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Здравствуйте.

Имеется адреса вида:

> http://site.ru/articles/news?page=N

где N - страница в разделе, т.е. любое число от 1 до бесконечности!

эти адреса нужно редиректить на адрес вида:

> http://site.ru/news/page/N

Пробую так:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/news /news/page/%1 [R=301,L]
```

не работает, что не так?

Comment: редирект тупо перекидывает на http://site.ru/news без /page/N в конце адреса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот собственно и решение вопроса:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/news /news/page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /page/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: А этот же редирект не учитывает смену адреса http://site.ru/articles/news на http://site.ru/news (т.е. articles должен выпадать)